# cannot connect mobile device to tomcat on Centos Linux

Tags: centos

i have my web services in local and run in Tomcat and it works (in local).
Now i want to connect from smartphone browser to this tomcat. For example my Pc have ip:`192.168.1.140` and my device:`192.168.1.3` (same network).

so in browser device i try: `http://192.168.1.140:8080/myservices`, but not work.

I think there is a problem in my configuration on Centos because my router i have disabled the firewall, i add on iptables to accept the connection on 8080 and 80 but still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve with this:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

service iptables save

service iptables restart
```